# Powershell: pipe a multi-line string to resolve-path's -LiteralPath

Tags: powershell, escaping, glob

Using Powershell, I want to convert a bunch of absolute paths to relative paths:

```
cmd /c dir /s /b /a-d | resolve-path -relative | sort-object
```

However, there are many funny characters in the directories that confuses Resolve-Path that it thought they were wildcard patterns.

How to pipe them to resolve-path's `-LiteralPath`?
I read that it should be done by ByPropertyName piping and that the value should be put to the "LiteralPath" property of the input object.

But I don't know how. The articles on the web confuse the hell out of me.

Please help and many thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Specify that the pipeline input value should be bound to `LiteralPath` instead, like this:

```
cmd /c dir /s /b /a-d|Resolve-Path -LiteralPath {$_} -Relative
```

---

Although, if you just want to recurse through the directory tree, gather all files and resolve their relative path, use `Get-ChildItem` instead - the `LiteralPath` parameter on built-in cmdlets is always aliased `PSPath`, which happens to be the name of a property that the providers add to all drive items, making the pipeline-binding work automatically:

```
Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse |Resolve-Path -Relative 
                                           # Explicit binding to LiteralPath no longer required
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with Powershell so I use the cmd/dir command, but you show how to do it right. Thanks!

Comment: Aside from the leading .\ is there a difference to `Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse -Name` ?

Comment: `Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse -Name` in Windows PowerShell 5.1 would work just the same :)

Comment: @LotPings `Get-Childitem -name` would only output a string instead of an object, but it would work in this case anyway.

Comment: @js2010 `-Relative` already causes `Resolve-Path` to output bare strings :)

Comment: Good point about `Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse -Name`, which should work in PowerShell _Core_ too, right? While there are a number of problems with `-Name`, in this simple case it seems to work fine.